# Multithreading in JavaFX same application

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have an issue with JavaFX and multithreading. Basically I have an application and the task at hand asks me that I should have multiple users. Like for example I have a bug-testing application which shows a list of bugs and users and testers can choose to add/delete bugs from this list(a tableview in my case). Building the application was not a problem, but I don't understand how to 'simulate' multiple users. The task says that when I run my program, 3 windows should appear(2 for users and 1 for a tester), and when I add/delete a bug, the tableview should get updated.

I believe I need to do this with threads, as my last course involved multithreading, but I'm at a loss here. My main class looks like this:

```
import controller.OfertaCtrl;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import repository.OfertaRepo;
import view.OfertaFXML;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main extends Application {
    private static Stage primaryStage;
    private static Scene MyPage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        //Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Main.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        setPage();

    }

    public void setPage() throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Oferte");
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("oferta.fxml"));
        Pane pane = loader.load();
        pane.setId("pane");
        MyPage  = new Scene(pane);
        OfertaRepo repo = new OfertaRepo("C:\\Users\\Mihai\\workspace\\lalal\\newGUI\\src\\oferte.txt");
        OfertaCtrl ctrl = new OfertaCtrl(repo);
        OfertaFXML ctrl2 = loader.getController();
        ctrl2.loadData(ctrl);
        primaryStage.setScene(MyPage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

So basically I take a list of 'offers' in this example from a .txt file and put them in an ObservableArrayList with which I work with in my Controller class. The problem lies in the fact that I don't understand how I need to run multiple threads of the same application. Also, how would I update my tableview for all windows when I modify it in an open window? I was thinking of doing light pooling on my ObservableArrayList and checking for alterations every 1 second or so.

I can provide more information or whatever is needed, I just need a few points on how to go about solving this problem.

Here's how the application looks right now:
[image: App]

Comment: Why do you think you need threading here? Why don't you just open three windows?

Comment: I think I'm required to do it with threading, so my threads communicate through the data structure in which I have my Bug-type objects(or Offers in my case). It does say that the instant I modify my tableview(by adding/deleting something) the other windows should get the table-view updated - so maybe light pooling isn't the way to go either - since that isn't instant, and it might become laggy if I have multiple users.

Comment: What do you mean "required to do it with threading"? You have three windows open: they all have to operate on the same thread anyway. So what background threads do you think you are "required" to have? Why not just share the same observable list with each window and use it as the items list for all the tables? Then the updates will all be automatic.

Comment: So I'd just have 3 stages with the same scene?

Comment: Umm, what? No. You can't even do that. Just open three windows, each with their own scene and contents, etc. Just share the same list with each of them.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by 'open 3 windows'. I updated my first post with a picture of how the App looks right now. Do I just run the app 3 times so I'd have 3 windows of the same thing? I'm sorry if this seems like common knowledge.

Comment: You said "when I run my program, 3 windows should appear". A window is a `Stage`. Just create two more stages and show them. It is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to try it that way then, thank you.